# Word order in questions

Tags: word-order, questions

I would need to know whether the following is correct:

**What should be your best friend like?** *//what character should your best friend have*

**What is his strange car for?** *//question*

**I do not know what his strange car is for.** *//the answer with different word order*

And one more question - I would like to ask what features your dream car should have. Could I use:
What should be your dream car like? *//maybe this is used only for people?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second and third examples are correct, but your first is not. It should be:

> What should your best friend be like?

Or, perhaps better:

> What would your ideal best friend be like?

In English questions with ordinary verbs, you invert the word order and add *do*:

> **I like** model trains.
>   **Do you like** model trains?

Verbs such as *be*, *should*, and *can*, however, don’t use *do*:

> **I am** okay.
>   **Are you** okay?
>   **I should** work on my project.
>   **Should you** work on your project?
>   **I can** help you.
>   **Can you** help me?

Your sentence just adds *what*, which doesn’t change the word order from a yes/no question:

> What **should I** do?
>   What **should he be** like?
>   What **should your best friend be** like?

If you wanted to ask about someone’s dream car, you would use *would* instead of *should*. A person is expected to have a best friend, so it makes sense to ask them what qualities a best friend *should* have. But not every person gets to own their dream car, so in that case it’s better to ask them what it *would* be like, *if* they were to own it.

Answer (score 1):

> What should be your best friend like?

Unless you are writing fiction or making a grade school fortune teller out of folded paper, I think you want something to the effect of *what **is** your best friend like?* or *describe your best friend*.

**EDIT:**  In light of your comment, I suggest *describe your ideal best friend*.

> What is his strange car for? / I do not know what his strange car is for.

Not sure what you mean by strange, but there is nothing wrong with the structure of that inquiry or response.

> What should be your dream car like?

You are close here.  You could say *what should your dream car be like?* or *describe your dream car*.

Comment: Thanks! Regarding the first one - its really like more like a question about hypothetical "ideal" best friend. He should be ...Hope I made myself clear now :)

Comment: @Pietro:  please see my edit.  :)